# How to fix "Object doesn't support property or method 'exportInfo' at button.print.min.js"

Tags: printing, datatables

Please refer below script to prepare table:

[image]

Please refer below js libraries loaded:

[image]

Please refer below UI of table and error after clicking on print button:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different versions of libraries was the cause of issue.

Using below library references fixed it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/pnp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/CSS/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/CSS/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/PWA/SiteAssets/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
```